# Is it normal for 2 HDD, from the same prodn lot, used in the same NAS for 6 years, to fail in the same way within a week of each other?

Tags: hard-drive, crash, nas

Hardware : Netgear ReadyNAS RN102 2-Bay running ReadyNAS OS 6.4
Hard Disks : 2x Seagate Barracuda 2TB ST2000DM001, mfg Thailand 04/2014, same model number, diff serial number
issue : beeping and clicking sound, NAS would not boot. disk1 crashed on Jan 4th. Disk 2 crashed Jan 11. Luckily I bought another drive and resynced RAID1 between those days so I didnt lose data. The new disk seems to be working fine so far, but i do think I hear some clicking sometimes (though i cant be absolutely sure I'm not imagining it.

Question: is this situation probable/possible in real life or is this an electrical fault that weakened/killed the disks? should I replace just the disks, the power brick, the entire NAS? what can I do to debug?

moreinfo: The NAS was connected to power through a power strip and I have now replaced it with a belkin surge protector. I also stripped and inspected each board in the NAS for any burnt components or charring. it looks clean. the one thing I did find out is that jiggling the power plug where it goes into the NAS can cause the NAS to lose power. the power port on the board seems solid so it might be the brick.

Comment: This could be anything. It could be that the drives came from the same batch and had the same built-in time-bomb, or it could simply be that in replacing one you knocked, or otherwise put stress on the other and provoking a borderline failure into actual failure. Rebuilding a RAID array would mean a long time copying data from an older drive to the newer one, meaning more head movement, more heat and work in general and could lead to it following the other drive sooner than it would have without the rebuild. When one drive goes in a NAS, you should consider the other drives "on borrowed time".

Comment: That might be it. I know I did a double resync by mistake. After the new drive resynced in RAID 1, I fiddled with the old drive and removed it for a moment. I thought RAID1 would only check the RAID array , but it did a full resync from the new drive to the old one. that full read and then full write might have finished the 2nd old drive.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for a consumer disk to fail after more than 5 years, as most such
disks are not rated for more than that.

If you wish for disks that are rated for 10 years or more, they are usually
labelled as "Enterprise" and go with a 10-year warranty.
They are also costlier.

Whatever the disk is rated as, sometimes you strike it lucky with a disk that
keeps on working much longer than its rating, and sometimes just the opposite.